# how can i print a histogram based on the counters of each flower species?(x axis- name of the flower y axis-the amount)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, counter, pie-chart

> ```
> #counters
> ```

```
counter_setosa = 0
counter_versicolor = 0
counter_virginica = 0
```

> ```
> #checking the name of the flowers and adding them to their counters
> ```

```
for item in df['species']:
```

> #for setosas(in loop)

```
  if item == 'setosa': 
    counter_setosa +=1
```

> #for versicolor(in loop)

```
  if item == 'versicolor':
    counter_versicolor +=1
```

> #for virginica(in loop)

```
  if item == 'virginica':
    counter_virginica +=1
```

> #priniting the counters and their names

```
print("setosa: ", counter_setosa)
print("versicolor: ", counter_versicolor)
print("virginica: ", counter_virginica)
```

Comment: A histogram should have continuous data on both axes. Do you mean a bar chart?

Comment: The bar command of matplotlib looks to be what you are looking for, it is not a 'histogram' but it will give you a bar plot to compare counts of your flowers.

Comment: So, you mean a [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a bar chart to get (what I assume is your) desired result:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random  # For creating example dataframe

# Define example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([random.choice(("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) for _ in range(100)], columns=("species",))

value_counts = df["species"].value_counts()

# Optional, just for checking the values are correct
print(value_counts)

# The important bit
plt.bar(value_counts.index, value_counts, width=0.4)
plt.xlabel("Species")
plt.ylabel("Number")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code has a problem. `types` and `value_counts` can be (and often are) in a different order.  You need to forget about `types` and use `value_counts` everywhere. Either `plt.bar(value_counts.index, value_counts)` or `value_counts.plot.bar()`.  The easiest solution is seaborn's `sns.countplot(data=df, x='species')`.